# CSS: Gradient defined by multiple classes?

Tags: css

Is it possible to define multiple classes, each with a background color. Then when an element has multiple of these classes, that the backgrounds fade as if a gradient? And do this in pure css (as I already have code that does it, but I'm wondering if there is a nicer way)?

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.wantedResult{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, green);
}
```

```html
<div class="red">Red</div>
<div class="green">Green</div>
<div class="red green">Both</div>
<div class="wantedResult">WantedResult</div>
```

As you can see, the "both" element only shows one of the backgrounds. But it should show both, as a gradient.

Is there any way to do this?

Note: Of course this is a very simple example, with only two colours it's no big deal to define the "wantedResult" class as well. But what if there are for instance ten used colours, it gets unmanagable very quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is clearly no CSS way to achieve this directly simply because the browser cannot know how should the gradient be defined when there is 2 or 3 colors. There is a lot of posibilities.

One way is to consider CSS variables to make think easier. The idea is to define the gradient with some default colors that you may change by chaging your variables. Again, this will not make what you want but it will, at least, avoid you defining a lot of gradient.

```css
.red_1 {
  --color1: red;
}
.red_2 {
  --color2: red;
}

.green_1 {
  --color1: green;
}
.green_2 {
  --color2: green;
}

.coloration{
  background: linear-gradient(var(--color1,pink),var(--color2,pink));
}

div {
 height:50px;
 margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="coloration">default</div>

<div class="coloration green_1 green_2">green</div>

<div class="coloration red_1 green_2">green red</div>

<div class="coloration red_2 green_1">green red</div>

<div class="coloration red_2 red_1">red</div>
```

Comment: Aha, it's been too long since I worked with css, I forgot about css variables!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why "both" shows only one color (green) is because the class "green" is defined after the class "red".

That means that if you have both classes on one element, the element will always have the color that is defined later (for example if you first define the class green - that is, write ".green{background-color: green;}", then "both" will show red, and vice versa).

If you **really** wanted to do this, you could probably do it with javascript by checking if the element has both classes and if it does, set the background as a linear-gradient.
But I wouldn't really suggest that, instead just make another class that has linear-gradient as background-color.

Comment: All about that cascade :)

Answer (score 1):

Although CSS will has no automatic command to do what you are looking for, you could of course cheat by manually overriding the double class with a new definition that has the gradient.

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red.green{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, green);
}

.wantedResult{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, green);
}
```

```html
<div class="red">Red</div>
<div class="green">Green</div>
<div class="red green">Both</div>
<div class="wantedResult">WantedResult</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to have a gradient background just by using 2 classes that both have a different *background-color* value. Seems like using linear-gradient is your only option here.

Maybe you could just have a bunch of gradient images with different color combinations depending on your needs, and then just set the image as background. That would make your styles more readable and manageable, although some might not consider this 'pure CSS'.